# How to configure vpp+dpdk NIC in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, dpdk

Cloned and compiled vpp stable2402 myself, running environment Ubuntu22 in Hyper-V.

I created the LagecyNetworkAdapter by default and I can see the number with lspci, but dpdk doesn't recognize it.
A normal network adapter I created, after uncommenting the dpdk configuration entry in etc/vpp/startup.conf, will boot successfully, and "ip a" will not see all the ethX, but neither will it be seen in vpp.

I created two more NICs.
DPDK officially gives only one command, driverctl -b vmbus set-override {DeviceID} uio_hv_generic.
After executing one of the two NICs and using "driverctl -b vmbus list-devices", the driver is changed to "uio_hv_generic [*]".
Another NIC dpdk will automatically convert hv_netvsc to uio_hv_generic.
But it doesn't do much, and I can't see the pci number, and it doesn't boot successfully, and crashes.

> vpp[pid]: perfmon: skipping source 'intel--uncore' - intel_uncore_init: no uncore units found
> Failed to save post-mortem API trace to /tmp/api_post_mortem.[pid]
> Aborted (core dumped)

The vpp official didn't give a valid example either.

I'm looking for guidance.